# Installing RStudioAMI on Amazon Web Services error:

Tags: r

I have set up an AWS and I am trying to install a package. I run the following but get an error.

```
> devtools::install_github("https://github.com/nwstephens/RStudioAMI.git")
Downloading GitHub repo nwstephens/RStudioAMI@master
✔  checking for file ‘/tmp/RtmpEH49ON/remotes33643b988bf8/nwstephens-RStudioAMI-8507ced/DESCRIPTION’
─  preparing ‘RStudioAMI’:
✔  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
   Warning in file(con, "r") :
     cannot open file 'man': No such file or directory
    ERROR
   computing Rd index failed:cannot open the connection
Error in (function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE,  : 
  System command error
```

Running also:

```
> install.packages("RStudioAMI")
Installing package into ‘/home/msmith/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘RStudioAMI’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

I have tried updating my R version.

```
> install.packages("installr")
Installing package into ‘/home/msmith/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘installr’ is not available (for R version 3.4.4)
```

I am not sure how I can proceed with this from here… Do you know of something I can run in the terminal to install this package?

EDIT: Using Ubuntu 18

Answer (score 0):

Solved (I think)

I downloaded the package from GitHub: https://github.com/nwstephens/RStudioAMI

Uploaded this .zip to the server and then;

In R studio I created a new Project and then selected build -> Build Source Package which seemed to work.